# What is the correct character set to use for '\xE7'

Tags: mysql, file-upload, character-encoding

I am trying to load data from a file into a MySQL table using

```
load data infile 'outfile2.txt' 
into table parsed_ingredients 
fields terminated by "," 
lines terminated by "\n";
```

All appears fine until I reach a line where this error gets thrown

```
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xE7ao' for column 'ingredient' at row 5875
```

I looked at the line and it's

```
ç (c-cedilla)
```

I have tried all sorts of combinations of encoding

```
utf8
latin1
uft8mb4
```

They are all leading to the same error. What is the correct encoding to use and what needs to be set to this encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of cp1250, cp1256, dec8, latin1, latin2, latin5 map the *single byte* `E7` to `ç`.  Use `latin1`.

Apparently your *client* is using `E7`, so you need to tell MySQL that fact.  Do that in the `LOAD DATA` statement with this between lines 2 and 3:

```
CHARACTER SET latin1
```

Meanwhile, the column in the table can be latin1 or utf8 or utf8mb4; it does not matter.  (Or, at least, it does not matter to *this* Question.)  The E7 will be translated to the suitable encoding for the table column.  For utf8/utf8mb4, expect to find hex `C2E7` in the table.

Comment: That was it! Thanks. And I had to add it to my `LOAD DATA...` statement. For some reason, setting it using `set character_set_client ...` etc. did not work. Thanks again.

Comment: @MattCremeens - Alas there are too many places where the character set encoding needs to be specified.